# How to detect specific attribute with specific text inside

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to be able to specify that IF data-path == "USB/sda1-usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_B" then do code etc data-path is my attribute.

Any idea how to do this with JS? document.getelementbyid i dont think has the extension for it but perhaps im wrong? I couldnt find anything anywhere for it.

I also know that you can use:

`document.getElementById("db-1").hasAttribute("data-path");`

But thats if it has it which it does but i want to check inside and match.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you use jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the `getAttribute` method

```
var attrValue = document.getElementById("db-1").getAttribute("data-path");
if ( attrValue == "USB/sda1-usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_B" )
{
  //your code here
}
```

Comment: Perfect! I tried directly going == but no luck, strange but wow haha thanks!

Comment: @irishwill200 glad to help!

Comment: @irishwill200 `getAttribute` != `hasAttribute`

Comment: @gurvinder372 How do you use this for exact string reference, so if i was looking for `USB` and the string had `USBs` i would want it to only show the one for `USB`?:)

Comment: @irishwill200 currently it is only matching the exact string reference since I am using `==` operator with the attribute value.

Comment: @gurvinder372 Hmm strange, it works if my data-path contains: `USB/sda1-usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_B` but then it also works if it contains: `USB/sda1-usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_B\anythingelseHERE`. So its meant to match it exactly? Thats what i was thinking. Il check it out thanks!:)

Answer (score 1):

This way ?

```
let path=document.getElementById("db-1").dataset.path;
if(path==="USB/sda1-usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_B"){
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Check that is better written in dot notation: `document.getElementById('db-1').dataset.path`

Comment: so much used to typescript

Answer (score 0):

The [HTMLElement.dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property allows access, both in reading and writing mode, to all the [custom data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-data-*) (data-*) set on the element. It is a [map of DOMString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOMStringMap), one entry for each custom data attribute.

Code:

```
var el = document.getElementById('db-1');

if (el && el.dataset.path === 'USB/sda1-usb-SanDisk_Cruzer_B') {
  // Your code...
}
```